# QMediaRecorder: Not compatible codecs and container format

Tags: c++, qt

У меня есть приложение, которому надо дать доступ к микрофону и начать записывать. Но выскакивает данная ошибка при начале записывания.

Пролистал интернет, установил gstreamer1.0(все пакеты) и переменную окружения менял на /usr/local/lib/gstreamer-1.0

Все в пустую, опять эта ошибка. Кто сталкивался с ней???
[image: log]

Comment: Добавьте в описание код, вызывающий проблему, и отредактируйте метки (либо укажите, каким образом Вы используете здесь Python).

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте, есть ли среди поддерживаемых используемый Вами кодек:

```
QAudioRecorder recorder;
for (const auto& codec : recorder.supportedAudioCodecs())
    qInfo() << codec;
```

Например, используемый в документации [AMR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_Multi-Rate_audio_codec) аудио кодек у меня в системе не установлен, соответственно, при запуске примера [audiorecorder](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtmultimedia.git/tree/examples/multimedia/audiorecorder?h=5.15) получаю вышеупомянутую Вами ошибку.

Для того, чтобы изменить кодек, необходимо сделать следующее:

1. Выбрать один из поддердживаемых кодеков (см. код выше)
2. Создать объекта типа `QAudioEncoderSettings`
3. Указать используемый Вами кодек
4. Применить настройки для рекордера

Пример:

```
QAudioRecorder recorder;

QAudioEncoderSettings settings;
settings.setCodec("audio/x-vorbis");
settings.setQuality(QMultimedia::HighQuality);
// и т.д., на Ваше усмотрение

recorder->setEncodingSettings(settings);
```

Comment: Спасибо, что ответили. Дело в том, что данное приложение это сторонний продукт, который я использую (на скрине просто его логи). Саппорт говорит, что все отлично работает, значит у меня что то не установлено. 

P.S. моя задача потом просто подключиться с помощью python к работающему приложению

Comment: @NGdust, тогда было бы правильно написать об этом в самом вопросе. Если Вы указываете тег C++ - подразумевается, что Ваш вопрос связан с разработкой программного обеспечения, но никак не с настройкой окружения или установкой определенных пакетов :) Сейчас посмотрю, что можно сделать, мне нужен более полный лог.

Comment: Обновил скриншот лога в вопросе :) Очень на вас надеюсь)))

Comment: @NGdust, смотрите, я нашел пример amr, на моем ПК он проигрывается, значит, необходимые кодеки установлены. Тем не менее, я по-прежнему не могу использовать "audio/amr". Это значит, что либо бэк аудио не поддерживает данный формат, либо что-то не так с Qt. Но я склоняюсь к первому варианту, и Вы можете это проверить используя вышеприведенный код. Другой вопрос, почему разработчики используемого Вами ПО не отображают в UI сообщении об ошибке - ведь они однозначно должны были проверить - поддерживается ли данный кодек или нет, перед тем, как его использовать.

Comment: я попробовал воспроизвести .amr файл, но ни чего. Походу и правда кодека нету. Только в интернете не могу найти как на Ubuntu установить данный кодек

Comment: @NGdust, еще раз акцентирую Ваше внимание на том, что установка кодека может не помочь. Посмотрите список поддерживаемых кодеков используя вышеприведенный код. Про Ubuntu ничего сказать не могу - сижу на Arch :)